# Inserting seed data on application startup fails all my test cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

In my web application I have to insert some seed data if not exists in DB when application got deployed. So, I have triggered inserting data api as follows

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextLoadListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

    @Autowired
    private PersistenceFacilitator persistenceFacilitator;
    @Autowired
    private SeedDataService seedDataService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        // generate metadata for entities and schema
        persistenceFacilitator.facilitate();

        //insert seed data
        seedDataService.insertSeedData();
    }

}
```

It's working fine. But the problem comes when I execute test cases with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`, that event got triggered and try to insert seed data though DB is not ready. So, all my test cases getting failed.

Is there a way to address this issue with spring or any good application start-up event to handle seed data?

[updated]
As per app engine specification to test inserting data into DB, I have to call

```
@Before
public void setup(){
   LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
   helper.setUp();
}
```

Which is not ready by the time application context loads. Anyway I don't want to insert seed data in DB while running testcases

Comment: Please specify why they fail an exception or something like that.
Related to the on start up. You can annotate any public void no argument method with  @PostConstruct and it get invoked by after bean creation. Which does usually what you want.

Comment: I am using google datastore to store data... And I am not able to create test DB by the time application context builds as I am initializing DB in @Before annotated test methods.

Comment: Please post a pit more information regarding your test class and if you get an exception or northing  happens, the method gets not executed or something more detailed.

Comment: Initializing the DB in an `@Before` method in your test is **too late**, since the `ApplicationContext` has already been loaded by that time. In other words, your `ApplicationListener` is executing _before_ the DB is initialized.

Comment: Please provide details on how you _initialize_ the database, so that we can analyze your options.